# Run singularity docker in cluster

Tags: linux, bash, docker, singularity-container

for a sientific projet I need to use the singularity project here :
https://github.com/Dfam-consortium/TETools

I manage to run it by running the Wrapper script : **bash dfam-tetools.sh**

then I get a new environment :

```
(dfam-tetools /beegfs/data/TOOLS/TETools)$
```

and then I can run all the software I need inside the docker.

But here is the problem, how can I run the same way in a cluster (exemple with `slurm` or `SGE` ? )

I tried to create a bash file such as :

**testrun.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
bash /beegfs/data/TOOLS/TETools/dfam-tetools.sh
RepeatModeler -h
echo "test"
```

But I only get as output:

```
/var/spool/slurmd/job2055108/slurm_script: line 3: RepeatModeler: command not found
test
```

Does someone have already ran a docker in a cluster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Since it is necessary to have access to another directory not in the current one, the singularity command should be run instead of the `dfam-tetools.sh` script:

```sh
singularity run -B /data:/data docker://dfam/tetools:latest RepeatModeler -h
```

**Original accepted answer:**

By looking at the documentation and the script `dfam-tetools.sh`, you should write:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
bash /beegfs/data/TOOLS/TETools/dfam-tetools.sh -- RepeatModeler -h
```

If you need more commands to be run, I suggest to write them into a bash file and to run this file as:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
bash /beegfs/data/TOOLS/TETools/dfam-tetools.sh -- bash myscript.sh
```

Read carefully the documentation as it is well written.

from chippycentra:
Edit : Thanks to frodon the following code worked for me :

singularit`y run -B //beegfs/data/user1/://beegfs/data/user1/ docker://dfam/tetools:latest BuildDatabase -name $Sp_name.DB -engine rmblast $ASSEMBLY`

where `/beegfs/data/user1/`is the path where are found the files

Comment: Ok Thank you but now I'm facing a new issue: since I am in the docker, the soft cannot find the file I'm calling : I get ```file does not exist!```, evene if I give the full path, I'm not really familiar with it, should I give a environment path as well ?

Comment: The `dfam-tetools.sh` script mount the current directory as `/work` in the container. If your file is in your current directory, write `/work/my_file` in your script `myscript.sh`.
You can also refer `/work` as `$HOME`.

Comment: And what if the file is not in the current directory for exemple /data/path1/path2/file.fa

Comment: Then, you have to run the singularity command yourself and provide a bound option:
`singularity run -B /data:/data docker://dfam/tetools:latest bash myscript.sh`

Comment: If you use docker, the command has more options: `docker run -it --rm --init --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/work --mount type=bind,source=/data,target=/data --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" --workdir "/work" --env "HOME=/work" dfam/tetools:latest bash myscript.sh` (obviously cannot test the command)

Comment: Ok so i juste gave singularity installed and not docker... So I do not really understand where I put the path where my file is in the commande : ```singularity run -B /data:/data docker://dfam/tetools:latest bash myscript.sh```sorry but I do not really understand how it works ... I ran your code and it seems to install something

Comment: The file `myscript.sh` is the one you write with all your commands. You can use its full path on your machine. Within this script you can mention files in `/data`, they will be found in the container thanks to the `-B /data:/data`option.

Comment: So is it ok if I do : ```singularity run -B /beegfs/data/user1:/beegfs/data/user1: docker://dfam/tetools:latest BuildDatabase -name $Sp_name.DB -engine rmblast /beegfs/data/user1/path1/path2/file.fa``` (since I run a slurm script I need to have the commands on the same line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225402/discussion-between-frodon-and-chippycentra).